# How to remove all handlers from dialog's close button?

Tags: 2013, jquery, list-form, modal-dialog

When any user clicks the close (X) button of the list edit form, I want to prevent closing it and to show an additional submission dialog. For this purpose I tried to remove all event handlers from this button with no luck in IE 11.

```
var btnClose = $("a.ms-dlgCloseBtn", parent.document);
$clearHandlers(btnClose.get(0));
btnClose.click(function () { showCloseDialog(); });
```

If I use `$clearHandlers` like in the code above, I get error `Out of stack space`. If I use `$removeHandler(btnClose.get(0), "click");` instead, I get `Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch` error.

`btnClose.off().find("*").off();` or `btnClose.removeAttr("onclick");` also don't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround solution. It isn't perfect, but it works.

I've replaced an original button with a cloned one, thus all the event listeners were removed from the new button. Here is an example of my code:

```
var btnClose = $("a.ms-dlgCloseBtn", parent.document);
var btnConfirm = btnClose.clone();
btnConfirm.attr("class", "custom-dlgConfirmBtn").click(function () { showCloseDialog(); });
btnClose.after(btnConfirm).remove();
```